# GitHub secrets are not sent and read correctly from file

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, github, github-actions

In my personal project, I try to deploy my backend spring boot with github actions and a Dockerfile

For more security, I save my properties in the Github secrets and in my Dockerfile, i get the configuration (url, username and password)

```
    - name: Build and push Docker image
    uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
    with:
      username: ${{ github.actor }}
      password: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      push: true
      file: ./Dockerfile
      tags: ${{ env.REGISTRY }}/***
      build-args: |
        server_port=${{ secrets.SERVER_PORT_DEV }}
        url=${{ secrets.URL_DEV }}
        username=${{ secrets.USERNAME_DEV }}
        password=${{ secrets.PASSWORD_DEV }}
```

And my spring boot doesn't run because the url, username and password are missing in my application.properties.
So, I try to cat the properties file in my github actions and here is what i got :

```
#11 0.281 # Secrets
#11 0.281 spring.datasource.url=
#11 0.281 spring.datasource.username=
#11 0.281 spring.datasource.password=
```

Do you have any idea why Github secrets are not read?
2nd more general question: is it good practice to use this method? Or are there better ones?

Thank you very much for your precious help and good day to all of you who would help me :)

Comment: Could you try using another action to write the properties file to check if the problem is with the action or the secrets? My suggestion: https://github.com/christian-draeger/write-properties

Comment: Hello, I try your solution but It does not work :/  The datas don't write on properties file

Answer (score 0):

The "[Set build-time variables (`--build-arg`)](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#set-build-time-variables---build-arg)" `docker build` man page section includes:

> The [`ARG` instruction](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#arg) lets Dockerfile authors define values that users can set at build-time using the `--build-arg` flag.
> This flag allows you to pass the build-time variables that are accessed like regular environment variables in the RUN instruction of the Dockerfile.
> Also, these values don’t persist in the intermediate or final images like [`ENV` values](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) do.

So make sure your Dockerfile includes:

```
ARG server_port
ARG url
ARG username
ARG password
RUN echo "spring.datasource.url=${url}">>application.properties && \
    echo "spring.datasource.username=${username}">>application.properties && \
    echo "spring.datasource.password=${password}">>application.properties
```

---

> I don't know if my syntax if incorrect or it's a problem with the GitHub secrets reading.

Actually, inside the Dockerfile, the GitHub Action secrets, like `${{ secrets.URL_DEV }}` would not apply.
Only `${url}`, meaning the `ARG` name, would be available.

So if you input text into `application.properties` in the Dockerfile, use the `ARG` variable names, not the GitHub Action secrets name.

But when you call `docker build` (*outside the Dockerfile, since docker build uses the Dockerfile), then yes, use the GitHub Action secrets:

```
docker build ----build-arg url=${{ secrets.URL_DEV }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in my Dockerfile I have this informations :

```
#Write the 3 args in a src/main/resources/application.properties file
RUN echo "spring.datasource.url=${url}" >> src/main/resources/application.properties
RUN echo "spring.datasource.username=${username}" >> src/main/resources/application.properties
RUN echo "spring.datasource.password=${password}" >> src/main/resources/application.properties

#Print the content of the file to check if it's ok
RUN cat src/main/resources/application.properties
```

I don't understand why my secrets doesn't in my file, i'm so confuse

Comment: Do you have the ARG lines, though, as I mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Yes of course : ARG server_port
ARG url
ARG username
ARG password
ARG hello

FROM openjdk:11-jdk


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR ./app
COPY . .

#Write the 3 args in a src/main/resources/application.properties file
RUN echo "spring.datasource.url=$url" >> src/main/resources/application.properties
RUN echo "spring.datasource.username=$username" >> src/main/resources/application.properties
RUN echo "spring.datasource.password=$password" >> src/main/resources/application.properties
RUN echo "test=$hello" >> src/main/resources/application.properties

Comment: Would a simple echo of those variables display the right values? Just for testing.

Comment: Test : 
build-args: |
            server_port=${{ secrets.SERVER_PORT_DEV }}
            url=${{ secrets.URL_DEV }}
            username=${{ secrets.USERNAME_DEV }}
ARG username
#5 [ 2/10] RUN echo "USERNAME ==> $username"
#5 0.218 USERNAME ==> 
#5 DONE 0.2s

Comment: So... does it display the actual value, or just the default value #5?

Comment: No, the #5 is just the dockerfile step showing by Github Action. The result of echo "USERNAME ==> $username" is USERNAME ==> 
I don't know if my syntax if incorrect or it's a problem with the github secrets reading.

Comment: Can you try `echo "url='${url}'"` instead of `echo "url='${{ secrets.URL_DEV}}'"`?

Comment: The echo command is the dockerfile command, not a github action command. When I try by github action the result is :
      - name: "Echo env"
        run: echo "URL-->${{ secrets.URL_DEV }}"
Run echo "URL-->***"
URL-->***

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant: can you try those echo in the Dockerfile, using url, not secrets.URL_DEV? Read my edited answer.